# Sway Random Wallpaper

Tags: raspberry-pi, manjaro

I am trying to load a random image from a folder to wallpaper.
In the sway.d folder, I have a .conf file that has one line that goes,

```
output * bg '$HOME/.config/sway/random_bg' fill
```

The random_bg file has multiple lines of codes that go,

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

import glob
import random
import sys

args = sys.argv[1:]

if len(args) == 0:
    args = [""]
walls = list()
for source in args:
    walls += glob.glob("/home/jake/.config/sway/bg/" + source + "/*.*")

print(random.choice(walls))
```

I have made random_bg executable by tying "chmod +x random_bg."
I have confirmed that it indeed works when I typed ./random_bg, it prints out the path of random images in the bg folder.
The issue is when I refresh sway, the screen just puts out a brownish gray color.
I can't figure out where the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried putting the script executable in your sway configuration? That way it should load every time sway refreshes.

```
vim ~/.config/sway/config
```

Here's the start of my sway config

```
# sway configuration file
exec waybar
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
del "C:\Users\empid\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\*.jpg"
del "C:\Users\empid\Pictures\deskwalls\ccimage\*.jpg"
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
cd "C:\Users\empid\Pictures\deskwalls"
set n=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    set /A n+=1
    set "file[!n!]=%%f"
)

for /L %%i in (1,1,%time:~-1%) do set "dummy=!random!"
set /A "rand=(n*%random%)/32768+1"
copy "!file[%rand%]!" "C:\Users\empid\Pictures\deskwalls\ccimage" 
del "C:\Users\empid\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\*.jpg"

xcopy /s C:\Users\empid\Pictures\deskwalls\ccimage\*.jpg  C:\Users\empid\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles
ren C:\Users\empid\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Themes\CachedFiles\*.jpg CachedImage_1366_768_POS2.jpg
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**